# Is there a bug on the reputation page with regard to viewing my reputation change?

Tags: support, reputation

[image]

So this green box supposedly displays the reputation I've gained or lost since my last visit to the reputation tab - however it seems to be tracking it for a longer period as if I refresh the page it does not reset to zero and I know I haven't gained 401 reputation in the recent past! Is this a bug or a mislabeled box or what?

Comment: "Reputation tab" doesn't mean that Activity page, it means the tab in the lower half of the screen (containing the tabs "Summary", "Answers", "Reputation, etc.). The url to that tab for your profile would be https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159763/ekolis?tab=reputation

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense - thanks!